# How do I address the current cell in a formula vs typing in the cell name (Ex: A2)?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm using the =IMPORTRANGE formuala to pull values from another spreadsheet and represent them in a comparison chart on another sheet. Here is the formula below.

=IMPORTRANGE("the link to my doc is here", "Wed. HEADCOUNT!C2")

^^^ this formula currently works. What I'd like to do is replace C2 with "currentcell" but this breaks the formula. I need to do this to repaste the formula hundreds of times without having to individually change each one.

Any thoughts?

I've tried putting in "currentcell", but this led to #REF error.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "virtual" reference to your current cell by using CELL("address",C2), which returns the address "C2", and then C2 will move when you copy the cell to another location.

So your formula will be this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("the link to my doc is here", "Wed. HEADCOUNT!" & CELL("address",C2))
```